# What's your suggestion for an effective and efficient file naming convention that works both in the cloud and locally?

Tags: file-management, google-drive

I work with hundreds of clients every year, each of whom generates dozens of files. These files may be generated by the clients themselves or by someone working closely with the client. In either case, the file contains information pertaining to the client, the type of work, date, location, and other miscellaneous pieces of data.

I would like to use a file naming convention such that they can be "queried" in a search bar to get exactly what I'm looking for.

I've already got a convention now that works for the most part - category, followed by date of work, followed by client's name, then followed by the type of work.

*Before I continue, let me point out briefly that we use Google Drive for cloud storage and [Google Drive File Stream](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=en) to make the contents in G-Drive appear and function like a second drive in the local filesystem. It would be ideal if any solution considered could work reliably in both spaces.*

The problem is that a minority of cases involve pluralities. Many clients could work on many projects lasting many days, all overlapping each other in various ways.

**Solution 1** would be to create one template file out of which as many copies are created as are necessary, and name each copy after a unique combination of client, work, date, etc. These files would differ only by name. This would work on both Google Drive and File Stream, but having many exact copies seems like a waste of space and leaves me with the impression that a better solution may exist.

**Solution 2** would be to intentionally leave the "plural" parts blank, and add them instead to the [file description](https://gsuitetips.com/tips/docs/add-a-description-to-your-google-docs/) in Google Drive. That way, there would be only one file for all overlapping clients, dates, and projects, saving the work of duplicating, but file descriptions do not carry over to File Stream. This method would only work reliably in Google Drive, and not in my local file explorer via File Stream. In effect, if I tried to search for any file containing "pluralities" in my file explorer, it wouldn't turn up any result.

**Solution 3** would be to simply add all overlapping details in the file name. Let's say I have 5 clients who worked on a project for 3 days. The resulting file for this case would have all of the clients' names, the project name, and 3 different dates in its name. Like solution 2, there would only be one file for all these different clients and dates, which saves space (trivial) and work spent duplicating (non trivial). Unlike solution 2, searching for this kind of file would work well in both Drive and in the file explorer. However, this would result in files with oddly long filenames, which are both unappealing and confusing to read at a glance.

Could you suggest something better? Something of a compromise that works well in both Google Drive and File Stream?

Answer (score 0):

### Use the right tool for the task.

File systems are not for complex categorization of information.

If Google Drive works well for you then just use only that.

Once you grow and solution won't fit to the increased complexity then you'll need a more specialised solution.

Comment: I was afraid this might be the case, but I think you're right.